# Give read access to another server

Tags: ubuntu

I have two ubuntu servers connected via private IP and have created a symlink on server 2 to access root directory of server 1 with:

**ln -s ~/server1 /server1_folder**

I need to browse a certain directory but it is telling me that Permission is denied.

**ls -l** gives me this

**drwx--x--- 1 10002 1003 4096 Sep 10 08:42 directory_name**

I need to give root user from server 2 access to read the folder on server 1, but cant find any way to do so.

Reason is I need to run fileconveyor on server 2 that checks a folder on server 1 and uploads files.

I'm connecting to server 2 via sshfs.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers in place of username(10002) /group ( 1003)  indicate that there is a problem in user permissions.

Look at chown/chgrp to setup the usernames/groups correctly.